# How to filter object by their child in Google Cloud Realtime Database?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database

So, I've Google Cloud Firebase Realtime Database, where objects stored and identified by their unique IDs. I need to filter them by their child property, for example, called `surname` where it would be exact match and get result of the whole object from promise. How to do that?
Example of how database looks like:

```json
{
    "uniqueID123": {
        "surname": "some surname",
        "data": "123"
    },
    "anotheruniqueID": {
        "surname": "some another surname",
        "data": "info"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To [order and filter data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#section-queries) you can use a query, like this:

```
const ref = db.ref('theParentNodeOfYourJSON');
ref.orderByChild('surname').equalTo("some surname").on('value', (snapshot) => {
  snapshot.forEach((child) => {
    console.log(snapshot.key, snapshot.child("surname").val());
  })
});
```

Comment: Typo of usage arrow function expression: `snapshot.forEach((child) => {`

Comment: And I using db variable as this:
`db: require('firebase/database').getDatabase(require('firebase/app').initializeApp({databaseURL: require(`dotenv`).config().parsed.DB_FIRE}))`

Comment: Shoud've wrote this in question itself, my bad.

Comment: I fixed that typo, but I'm not sure what to do with your other comments. Did you try the approach that I explained? What happened when you did? Was there an error message (aside from the missing `=>`)?

Comment: Thank you, I figured it out myself after, thanks to your answer.